# Trying to reverse a string in C++, but gibberish appears at the of the reversed string?

Tags: c++, string

Here is my function to reverse a string:

```
void reverse(char *str){

    int lengthStr = strlen(str);
    int j, i;
    char reversedString[100];

    for (j = 0, i = lengthStr-1; i >= 0; i--, j++){
        reversedString[j] = str[i];
    }

    cout << reversedString;
}
```

The string does appear as reversed, but at the end there's a bunch of weird characters that appears. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Where did you null terminate the reversed string?  Nowhere…which is why you get junk at the end.  Also, you are dealing with C strings, not C++ strings.

Comment: if you are really using C++ avoid char reversedString[100]

Comment: `std::reverse_copy` does this already. Alternatively, take a `std::string` and make a new string using its `rbegin()` and `rend()`.

Comment: @JaviV Then what do you suggest.

Comment: @chris Yes I know, but this is for learning purposes.

Comment: Take a look at the string documentation: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/ you have append, push_back or += operator. If you do that it would be much better but much slower. Because of that, you better do first  `reversedString.reserve(lengthStr)`

Comment: It would be a good idea to ensure that `lengthStr` is strictly less than `100` to prevent buffer overflow (a stack overflow, in fact).

Comment: You also need to check that `lengthStr < 100`.

Comment: @user3849925 See my answer. By the way you marked as the best answer an answer that is not good. I would even say that you marked a bad answer.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Can you please explain why my answer is so bad. I know this is not the best way to reverse the string but `user3849925` want to know why this is happening instead of what is the best way to reverse the string.

Comment: @Learner the function has to reverse the original string. You did not point out that the function in the post is invalid also because it is trying to write the result in the local variable that can be even less than the original string. To use memset only that to set elements of the array to 0 is a bad idea. You could write simply at least like  char reversedString[100] = {}; Again what is the magic number 100?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I completely agree with you. But why are you making assumption that user want to change the original string. He even not returning the local reversed string.

Comment: @Learner If the original string shall not be changed then the parameter has to be declared as const char *. In this case the function could be called with string literals.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow One last thing do you think the solution you have posted reverse the string. Please check it has a bug.

Comment: @Learner it had a typo. Nevertheless thanks that you pointed out it.

Comment: Depending on the encoding of your string the naïve solution presented by many answers only work for the ASCII character subset of the Unicode character set. As you are using `char` I would assume you're also using UTF-8. So you need to care about tailing bytes, as well as combining characters, resulting in reversing the grapheme clusters within the string. Actually you should use a decent Unicode library to help you solve this problem, it isn't as easy as you might think. Take a look at the ogonek library (https://github.com/rmartinho/ogonek) for instance, it will help you find these clusters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reverse the string there are many cleaner approaches already available like: `std::reverse_copy` etc.
But if you want to fix this function then try this:

```
char reversedString[100];
memset(reversedString, 0, 100*sizeof(char);
```

**OR**

```
for (j = 0, i = lengthStr-1; i >= 0; i--, j++){
    reversedString[j] = str[i];
}

reversedString[j] = '\0'; //! Add null character at the end to indicate end of the string
cout << reversedString;
```

**Note:** Your program fails if input string has `length >= 100`.

Answer (score 1):

Add a zero to the characters you assigned to `reversedString`. Otherwise, the unitialized extra portion of the new string will show up as garbage. A zero is used to mark the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the function is invalid and has no sense. You do not reverse the original string and the local string that is defined in the function can be less than the original string. Also you do not append the reversed local string with the terminating zero. The function can look like

```
void reverse( char *str )
{
    size_t n = std::strlen( str );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        char c = str[i];
        str[i] = str[n - i - 1];
        str[n - i - 1] = c;
    }
}
```

The original reversed string can be displayed in the code that calls the function.